# Google App Engine - GAE will not set Default TimeZone

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have tried the following so I can get Date based on my timezone which is `"Africa/Johannesburg"`  or `GMT+2:00` but Google servers always return time using its own timezone which is 2 hours behind mine.

I have done the FF:

in `appengine-web.xml` I have set

```
<property name="user.timezone" value="Africa/Johannesburg"/>
```

I have also tried  `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2:00"));` before creating Date object

in the init method of my servlet, I have also tried

```
@Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
         TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2:00"));
    }
```

But this thing won't just work. Because JDK date is not thread safe, I am using JodaTime, which works well, In fact when I do `new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Africa/Johannesburg"))` I get correct time but for legacy issues, I have to store date in JDK date hence have to convert Joda to JDK Date by invoking .Date(), then the time is completely screwed up in wrong timezone.

Does anyone by chance know how to set this without having to subtract the hours difference.

Comment: In my application, converting from `DateTime` to `Date` works. In the datastore, however, it is stored as UTC, but if you know that it's fine. Maybe you should save the timezone along with your date and convert it when reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The system timezone is not changeable. You should store all of your dates in unix time and convert them to a Date or Calendar object using your timezone. I also would not assume that GAE is always going to use the same timezone...

Comment: Thanks for your response, Do you mind showing the source of your claim? thanks

Comment: In the python the docs state Date-time values are stored as and returned using the UTC time zone. See datetime.datetime for a discussion of how to manage time zones.   Java will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you save any date in Datastore it will be saved in the timeZone you have set in your JVM, thats why before starting the app I always set it to UTC:

```
//To avoid difference of dates depending on where the server is located
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Nonetheless when you browse the datastore in the gcloud console it will be shown in your local timezone (probably it gets the browser timezone and adapts the response to you). But when you query it back the calendar date taken in count will be the one you used for saving it (In my case UTC).